# PlatformException, Invalid Argument after trying to mock file_picker for integration test, Flutter

Tags: flutter, mocking, integration-testing, filepicker.io, flutter-integration-test

I already use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) in my apps, and now I create an integration test.
I've been looking for a way to mock file_picker or dependencies, and this is the result:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() async {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setUp(() {
    mockFilePicker();
  });

  testWidgets("test", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // await app.main();
    // .. test case ..
  });
}

mockFilePicker() {
  const MethodChannel channel =
      MethodChannel('miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker');
  channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    print("MockMethodChannel run");

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/ic_bill.png');
    Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File file = await File(
      '${tempDir.path}/image.png',
    ).writeAsBytes(bytes);

    PlatformFile platformFile = PlatformFile(
        name: "image.png", size: file.lengthSync(), path: file.path);
    FilePickerResult filePickerResult = FilePickerResult([platformFile]);
    return filePickerResult;
  });
}
```

With that code, I get an error like this:

> [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception: PlatformException(error, Invalid argument: Instance of 'FilePickerResult', null, null)

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't seem to get any issue in setting up the mock file picker the way you did. What does the body of your actual test case that uses the mock file picker look like?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the channel method call is expecting a list of maps instead of FilePickerResult object. The format of the map is:

```
{
  'name': String,
  'path': String,
  'bytes': Uint8List,
  'size': int,
}
```

The following mock channel worked for me:

```
  const MethodChannel channelFilePicker =
      MethodChannel('miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker');

  TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
      .setMockMethodCallHandler(channelFilePicker,
          (MethodCall methodCall) async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/icon/Icon.png');
    final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = await File(
      '${tempDir.path}/tmp.tmp',
    ).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    print(file.path);
    return [
      {
        'name': "Icon.png",
        'path': file.path,
        'bytes': bytes,
        'size': bytes.lengthInBytes,
      }
    ];
  });
```